# Excel VBA - parse data from cell into array

Tags: excel, vba

I have data in one cell (E2) that consists of numbers separated by a comma and a space (i.e. `1, 14, 33, 46, 22, 3`). There can be up to 1,000 numbers in the cell. I want to take these numbers and put them in an array so I can then match them to a variable I call `AudienceNumber`. If the array contains the number `1` or the `AudienceNumber` I want to write the row that I built the array from (row 2 in this case) to a new workbook. If the array doesn't contain `1` or the `AudienceNumber` I want to go to cell E in the next row and repeat the process. I want to continue doing this until cell E is blank. I can't seem to get the contents of cell E2 into the an array. Here's what I got:

```
Dim AudienceArray (1000) as Variant
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Select
Range("E2").Select
AudienceArray=Sprlit(ActiveCell.Value,",")
```

When I run the sub I'm getting  a

> Can't Assign to Array Error

message. I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Change `Dim AudienceArray (1000) as Variant` to `Dim AudienceArray as Variant` and you might want to correct the spelling on `Sprlit`. Other than that it should work.

Comment: Using `Option Explicit` would have caught that `Sprlit` typo. There is never a good reason to not use `Option Explicit`. It isn't a bad idea to make it automatic by selecting `Require Variable Declaration` in the options tab of the VBA editor.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

    Sub Test()

        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim val As String
        Dim arr As Variant
        Dim i As Long

        Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
        val = ws.Range("E2").Text
        arr = Split(val, ",", -1, vbBinaryCompare)

        For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
            Debug.Print arr(i)
            'split retains spaces...
            Debug.Print Trim$(arr(i))
        Next i

    End Sub
```